# Setting width 100% in scale3d

Tags: css

**Motivation for question:**

The beautiful radio buttons from [here](https://codepen.io/BuddyLReno/pen/boGRPO) do not work when the `max-width` of the `form` is increased. How to fix this?

**Question:**

I would like to substitute the hard-coded `56` by the width of the `.inputGroup`.

```
.inputGroup input:checked ~ label:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(56, 56, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Setting `scale3d(100%, 56, 1)` does not work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing width of .inputGroup label :before from 10px to 100%.

Comment: Very smart! The following works: (1) set the `width` of `.inputGroup label :before` from `10px` to `100%`, and (2) set the `transform` of `.inputGroup label input:checked ~ label:before` to `translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(105, 50, 1);`